Having trouble making rotated divs touch left and right of parent div
I am making a hand viewer specific to the card game Euchre. It displays the four hands that have 5 cards each. I have the North and South hands right, but the East and West hands, which are rotated, are leaving empty blank space that I don't want. I know this is because it was rotated in the center x and y axis (I left the East hand unrotated so you can see what I'm saying), but I'm not sure how to fix it. I feel like I'm missing something simple but I'm not sure what.
Here is my HTML:
<div class="euchre-table">
    
    <img class="turn-up" src="resources/images/cards/9-C.png">
    
    <div class="hand hand-1">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/10-H.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/Q-H.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/K-H.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/A-H.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/J-H.png">
    </div>
        
    <div class="hand hand-2">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/10-S.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/Q-S.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/K-S.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/A-S.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/J-S.png">
    </div>
        
    <div class="hand hand-3">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/10-D.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/Q-D.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/K-D.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/A-D.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/J-D.png">
    </div>
        
    <div class="hand hand-4">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/10-C.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/Q-C.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/K-C.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/A-C.png">
        <img src="resources/images/cards/J-C.png">
    </div>
        
</div>

And here is my CSS:
.euchre-table {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px auto;
    width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.euchre-table .turn-up {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.euchre-table .hand {
    display: inline-block;
}

.euchre-table .hand-1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) rotate(90deg);
}

.euchre-table .hand-2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.euchre-table .hand-3 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10px;
    transform: translate(0, -50%) /*rotate(-90deg)*/;
}

.euchre-table .hand-4 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

.euchre-table img {
    height: 100px;
    width: 70px;
}

The result is in an image below. Again, I left the East hand unrotated so you can see what I mean about the blank whitespace.
This is the result
I tried doing a negative pixel property like -120px on the left property, but when I would remove one or more of the card images, it would go outside of the parent. I figured out this is because the less cards there are, the width of the div also shortens, which means the negative left value pushes it back further.
I also played around a lot with the transform-origin property, but got nowhere.
Note: The 9 of clubs in the center is not part of the East hand, but it is the turn-up card.
This is my first time asking a question, so I'm sorry if I did anything wrong. Thanks in advance

This could absolutely be done with some rotates and math, but I thought maybe I'd first suggest- what if you used a graphic resource that was already rotated, and you had a different element for horizontal and vertical cards? I don't know if it would be the best solution, but it would make the code pretty straightforward. I'll still look over the rotation issue as well.

If I understand correctly, your problem is that you are rotating the whole hand, when what you really want to do is rotate the cards individually. This would present a problem, where your hand container is not spaced to evenly hold the rotated cards.
In my demo, the way I will accomplish the desired visual effect is by having a flex container holding squares, which can be laid out in a column or row.
Then, the square will act as an anchor for a card element, which will overflow it's parent. The sizing of the card is defined by a css variable, which the hand container knows beforehand, and can adapt the padding of it's container to adapt to how much space the card elements need.
When vertical, the hand element will simply swap it's block padding and it's inline padding that we previously calculated, and the cards will rotate. This makes it easy to add more cards, or adjust as needed.
I hope the demo is clear and speaks for itself, if you have any questions, please don't hesitate to reach out.


/* THIS CSS IS ONLY TO HELP WITH VISUAL IDENTIFICATION OF ELEMENTS */


.hand {
    outline: 2px solid transparent;
    transition: outline 0.5s;
}

.hand:hover {
    outline: 4px solid hotpink
}

.card-anchor {
    background-color: #000;
}

.card {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.card:hover {
    opacity: 0.2;
}

/* END DEBUGGING CSS FOR VISUALISATION */

.hand {
    --card-width: 50px;
    --card-height: calc(var(--card-width) * 1.5);
    --padding: 20px;
    --card-height-offset: calc(var(--card-height) - var(--card-width));
    --block-padding: calc(var(--card-height-offset)/2 + var(--padding));
    padding-block: var(--block-padding);
    padding-inline: var(--padding);
    display: flex;
    gap: var(--padding);
    position: absolute;
}

.card-anchor {
    --size: var(--card-width);
    height: var(--size);
    width: var(--size);
    position: relative;
}

.card {
    height: var(--card-height);
    width: var(--card-width);
    background: hotpink;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    translate: -50% -50%;
}

.vertical.hand {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding-inline: var(--block-padding);
    padding-block: var(--padding);
}

.vertical.hand .card-anchor {
    rotate: 90deg;
}

.hand:not(.vertical) {
    left: 50%;
    translate: -50% 0;
}

.vertical.hand {
    top: 50%;
    translate: 0 -50%;
}

.top.hand { top: 0; }

.left.hand { left: 0; }

.bottom.hand { bottom: 0; }

.right.hand { right: 0; }
<div class="bottom hand">
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="left vertical hand">
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="top hand">
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="right vertical hand">
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-anchor">
        <div class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>




Thanks for taking the time to answer. I don't get what the --card-height-offset and --block-padding  calculations are for in .hand; is it to make it more responsive or something? Why can't the block-padding in .hand just be a fixed value? Other than those 2 lines I think I get the general idea.

Used the anchor concept. It worked, thanks!

@Jurtle09 You could use a fixed value if you don't adjust anything, but in the demo they help explain how I came to those values through calculations. The block-padding is important to give the .hand wrapper space for the overflowing card element and consistent padding. Storing the block padding in a variable makes it easy and clear to switch when going from row to column layout on vertical .hand.
I'm glad the anchor concept worked for you! Good luck out there
